# Recommend to be Protected

Tags: discussion, support

[I am familiar with the privilege.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)

But for users without the rep, is the 'flag' function a viable means to recommend to a Moderator that a question should be protected, or is this not the right method?

[What do I do if a teacher fails me after they said I'd pass?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/100930/what-do-i-do-if-a-teacher-fails-me-after-they-said-id-pass/100935#100935)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also drop a line in chat: there there are frequently a couple of high-rep users hanging around who can protect questions (though 15k+ users should wait a bit more than mods to protect a question).

However, I'm not sure I'd protect that question right now, the situation doesn't seem so bad to warrant protection.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

However, questions are generally protected only when they are attracting large numbers of junk answers or comments or other unwanted behavior by low rep users is taking place.